# Gtk# Multiple File Filter

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#, gdk

I want to display only image files in GTK# File Chooser

```
        fc.SelectMultiple = true;
        FileFilter filter  = new FileFilter();
        filter.Name = "Image files";
        filter.AddPattern ("*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.tif;*.bmp;*.gif;*.tiff");
        fc.Filter = filter;
```

This does not work.The file chooser does not show any Files.
Can someone suggest me a proper way to do this.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? Strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [sample from the docs](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.FileChooserWidget%2f%2a), the [`AddPattern` method](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aGtk.FileFilter.AddPattern%28System.String%29) is meant for adding a *single* pattern at a time. In contrast to the WinForms implementation and similar implementations, it does not *set* all patterns at a time, instead it *adds* one additional pattern to whatever has been added before.

Therefore, try splitting up your command:

```
fc.SelectMultiple = true;
FileFilter filter  = new FileFilter();
filter.Name = "Image files";
filter.AddPattern("*.jpg");
filter.AddPattern("*.jpeg");
filter.AddPattern("*.png");
filter.AddPattern("*.tif");
filter.AddPattern("*.bmp");
filter.AddPattern("*.gif");
filter.AddPattern("*.tiff");
fc.Filter = filter;
```